# Van-der-Waals Gas

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

I'm having trouble trying to solve one question, can someone help?
We have a gas where:

$$ p = \frac{RT}{v-b} - \frac{a}{v^{2}} $$

and

$$ u = RcT - \frac{a}{v} $$

Assume that we have an adiabatic process from $ T_{0} $ to $T_{1}$

I'm trying to find the relation between $V$ and $T$ and the work, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Also

$$p(u,v) = R\ln\left[(v-b)\left(u-\frac{a}{v}\right)^{c}\right] $$

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself:

$$ du = RcdT + \frac{a}{v^{2}} $$

Then we use : $ du = -pdV = -\frac{RTdv}{v-b} - \frac{adv}{v^{2}}$
We can simplify to find: $$ c\frac{dt}{T} = - \frac{dv}{v-b}$$